# Mysql INNER JOIN with multiple IDs and Tables

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I cannot figure how to do this but I believe what I need is to use INNER JOIN.

I have two tables. 
Table one is called "paths" and table two is called "filelinkpath".

```
  The "path" table looks like this
```

| **idPath** | **strPath** |
|.......4......|...../folder/folder/.....|

```
  The "filelinkpath" table looks like this
```

| **idShow** | **idPath** |
|.....22......|.....4.....|

I need to somehow get the strPath by using the idShow.

Comment: do you want us to write code for you?

Comment: agree with @Lashane : not even your question is clear

Comment: Sorry guys I was literally falling asleep when I was writing this question out. I didn't expect to have it written out for me I just didn't understand how to even go about laying out this mysql statement. It appears varad mayee below may have answered the question, I'll give it a try when I have a moment and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT strPath from path INNERJOIN filelinkpath ON path.idPath = filelinkpath.idPath
```

Comment: while this code block might answer the question, always try to improve your answer with relevant explanation see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @SMR ok i will be careful next time

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL:

```
SELECT strPath from path JOIN filelinkpath ON path.idPath = filelinkpath.idPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should do this.

```
CREATE TABLE path(idPath int, strPath varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE filelinkpath(idShow int,idPath int,FOREIGN KEY(idPath) REFERENCES  path(idPath));
INSERT INTO path values(4,'/folder/folder/');
INSERT INTO path values(20,4);
SELECT p.strPath FROM path p INNER JOIN filelinkpath f ON p.idPath = f.idPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an SQL statement without worrying about the JOIN statement you can use this:

```
select path.strPath from path,filelinkpath where path.idPath=filelinkpath.idPath and filelinkpath.idShow=22;
```